# Yii collecting data from two models into single form

Tags: php, forms, yii

In    my    web    application   I   need   to  collect  data  from  two  models  in  a   single   form.   The   first  model    form   is   like   an   update   action   for   making changes   in     existing      data   and   the   second   form   is   for   creating   a   new     record. Below is    the      code      I     tried   but when I click "save"      button Its not saving and redirecting instead     it     is         just     staying in the same page and the  changes I made are reverting back to their previous  values for I model and second model the attribute are becoming empty.

My code for  the controller

```
public function actionBookvegetable($id){
    $BookVegetable=new BookVegetable;
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        if(isset($_POST['ProducerOffer'])AND (isset($_POST['BookVegetable'])) ) {



        $model->attributes=$_POST['ProducerOffer'];
        $BookVegetable->attributes=$_POST['BookVegetable'];
        if($ProducerOffer->validate()  AND  $BookVegetable->validate()) {
            $BookVegetable->save();



        $BookVegetable->booked_by=Yii::app()->user->id;
        $BookVegetable->producer_offer_id=$model->id;

        $model->save();

        }
        if (($model->hasErrors() === false)&&($BookVegetable->hasErrors===false))
        {
            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
          }
    }
        else
        {

            Yii::app()->user->setReturnUrl($_GET['returnUrl']);
        }
        $this->render('book',array('model'=>$model,'BookVegetable'=>$BookVegetable));
        }
```

My code for the view  form.

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm',array('id'=>'non-ajax_form','enableAjaxValidation'=>false,)); ?>
<p class="help-block">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model,$BookVegetable); ?>
<?php echo "<br>" ?>

<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'vegetable_id', CHtml::listData(Vegetable::model()->findAll(),'id', 'name'), array('prompt'=>'Select Vegetable')); ?>


<?php echo CHtml::encode($model->getAttributeLabel('offered_qty')); ?>

<?php echo CHtml::textField("offered_qty",$model->offered_qty,array('readonly'=>true)); ?>


<?php echo CHtml::encode($model->getAttributeLabel('unit_cost')); ?>

<?php echo CHtml::textField("unit_cost",$model->unit_cost,array('readonly'=>true)); ?>

<?php echo CHtml::encode($model->getAttributeLabel('unit_delivery_cost')); ?>


<?php echo CHtml::textField("unit_delivery_cost",$model->unit_delivery_cost,array('readonly'=>true)); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::textField("booked_quantity",$BookVegetable->booked_quantity); ?>


</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div>  





<div class="form-actions">
    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array('buttonType'=>'submit', 'type'=>'primary', 'label'=>  'Save',)); ?
```

> 

How should I resolve this Anybody help me out .I am unable to debug the source of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saving the values before assigning the requested values.

Try this code, if it works:

```
public function actionBookvegetable($id){
    $BookVegetable=new BookVegetable;
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);
    if(isset($_POST['ProducerOffer'])AND (isset($_POST['BookVegetable'])) ) 
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['ProducerOffer'];
        $BookVegetable->attributes= $_POST['BookVegetable'];

        /*** The below two lines should be before "$BookVegetable->save()" function ***/
        $BookVegetable->booked_by=Yii::app()->user->id;
        $BookVegetable->producer_offer_id=$model->id;

        /*** Validate() function will check for the errors **/
        if($ProducerOffer->validate()  AND  $BookVegetable->validate()) 
        {
            $BookVegetable->save();
            $model->save();
            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
        }
        /***There is no need to check again for the errors as validate() will do that, So you can comment this three lines ***/
        /**if (($model->hasErrors() === false)&&($BookVegetable->hasErrors===false))
        {
        $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
        } */
    }
    else
    {
        Yii::app()->user->setReturnUrl($_GET['returnUrl']);
    }
    $this->render('book',array('model'=>$model,'BookVegetable'=>$BookVegetable));
}
```

Try changing these input text fields in your view file:

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'vegetable_id', CHtml::listData(Vegetable::model()->findAll(),'id', 'name'), array('prompt'=>'Select Vegetable')); ?>

 /*** The first field for below input text field is for "name" of the text fields, so this must follow "ModelName[field_name]" format **/
<?php echo CHtml::textField("ProducerOffer[offered_qty]",$model->offered_qty,array('readonly'=>true)); ?>


<?php echo CHtml::textField("ProducerOffer[unit_cost]",$model->unit_cost,array('readonly'=>true)); ?>

<?php echo CHtml::textField("ProducerOffer[unit_delivery_cost]",$model->unit_delivery_cost,array('readonly'=>true)); ?>

<?php echo CHtml::textField("BookVegetable[booked_quantity]",$BookVegetable->booked_quantity); ?>
```

I hope this would definitely work.. :)

Comment: Ya tried that its not working the result is the same

Comment: How are you posting two forms data using one Submit button ?
I hope there is only one "FORM" widget in your current Page..
Why don't you paste your view page contents..

Comment: even if I use just one form like if i use create action of one controller to create  the  object of another controller it is not saving,  for eg if i use producrOffer controller  action create to create an object of  BookVegetable controoler , it is  not saving at all

Comment: I have already posted it, my code for the view form where I enter the data

Comment: Oh, I see now..I got the error..
Can you tell me exactly which fields from which Models.
If I am right, fields "offered_qty","unit_delivery_cost", "unit_cost" are from ProducerOffer model and only one field i.e.
"booked_quantity" is from BookVegetable Model..

Comment: Ya exactly... That  is how I need it

Comment: Ok, so changed the above answer. Do see it.Actually the error is in your view file. The name of text field must follow "ModelName[table_field_name]" format..

Comment: Ya thku very much it works perfectly. that code works  perfectly